# Get Matrix where sum of each row, column and diagonal is equal to each other

Tags: python, list, matrix, input, sum

A Python Prgoram where the SUM of each Rows, Columns and Diagonals is equal to each other
and the size of the square Matrix is taken as input from the user:

I m trying to build a python function where the user can input the size of the square matrix where each Row, Column and Diagonal has same sum.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short way of doing this -

```
def square_matrix(size):
  matrix = [[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
  
  # Calculate the sum of each row, column, and diagonal
  sum = size * (size**2 + 1) / 2
  
  # ensure that sum of each row, column, and diagonal is equal to calculated sum
  for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
      if i == j:
        matrix[i][j] = sum
      elif i + j == size - 1:
        matrix[i][j] = sum
      else:
        matrix[i][j] = 0
        
  return matrix

# You can prompt the user for inputting a specific number and create the matrix based on that
print(square_matrix(5))
```